# Not working when using omnifaces and pretty url

Tags: jsf, omnifaces

I have this pretty url

```
<url-mapping id="testt">
        <pattern value="/test/" />
        <view-id value="/faces/test.xhtml" />
</url-mapping>
```

and i have this omniface

```
<o:form  useRequestURI="true"> 
    <h:commandButton value="test"/>
</o:form>
```

but when i click the url /test/1 when i click the command button instead of loading the /test/1 again it loads the faces/test.xhtml where is the problem?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Chances are your mapping needs to be :

```
<url-mapping id="testt">
    <pattern value="/test/#{id}" />
    <view-id value="/faces/test.jsf" />
</url-mapping>
```

Notice the `.jsf` instead of `.xhtml`. I'm guessing your `FacesServlet` is registered for test.xhtml thus transforming it in test.jsf.

Notice the `#{id}` after the slash. It is used to transmit url paramaters such as you're doing with  `/test/1` where 1 is the aforesaid parameter.